# Geoserver SLD style - double dashed line

Tags: geoserver, sld

Is it possible to make SLD style for Geoserver maps to represent street that has 3 tracks (or more) with something like this

[image]

I know that it is possible to make single dashed line ------ so the street will apear to have 2 tracks, but I was unable to make double dashed or triple dashed line.  I just need to represent each track on street.

I think it might be possible with using custom shape along with textsymbolizer and then making it appear as double dashed line, but I cannot use that because of all vendor options for displacement cause I will have street name, street direction etc. also with textsymbolizer.... I was wondering is it possbile with some line displacement or something similar?

Thx :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the `offset` function ( http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/filter/function_reference.html ). So you calculate a offset of e.g. +4 +2 -2 and -4 for your street. The +4 and -4 offset lines could be styled solid and the +2 and -2 offset lines could be styled dashed and in a different color. But you will still have a problem at the road links because the lines will be overlapping or there will be gaps.

Be aware that the geoserver needs to calculate an offset for 4 lines in realtime which could slow down performance. If the data is not changing you can use the GWC to serve tiles.